# Replacing only the first space in a string

Tags: java

I want to replace the first space character in a string with another string listed below. The word may contain many spaces but only the first space needs to be replaced. I tried the regex below but it didn't work ...

```
Pattern inputSpace = Pattern.compile("^\\s", Pattern.MULTILINE);  
String spaceText = "This split ";    
System.out.println(inputSpace.matcher(spaceText).replaceAll("&amp;emsp;"));
```

**EDIT:: It is an external API that I am using and I have the constraint that I can only use "replaceAll" ..**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because it doesn't account for the characters between the start of the string and the white-space.

Change your code to:

```
Pattern inputSpace = Pattern.compile("^([^\\s]*)\\s", Pattern.MULTILINE);  
String spaceText = "This split ";    
System.out.println(inputSpace.matcher(spaceText).replaceAll("$1&amp;emsp;"));
```

**Explanation:**

`[^...]` is to match characters that don't match the supplied characters or character classes (`\\s` is a character class).

So, `[^\\s]*` is zero-or-more non-white-space characters. It's surrounded by `()` for the below.

`$1` is the first thing that appears in `()`.

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**The preferred way**, however, would be to use `replaceFirst`: (although this doesn't seem to conform to your requirements)

```
String spaceText = "This split ";
spaceText = spaceText.replaceFirst("\\s", "&amp;emsp;");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `String.replaceFirst()` method to replace the first occurence of the pattern

```
System.out.println(" all test".replaceFirst("\\s", "test"));
```

And `String.replaceFirst()` internally calls `Matcher.replaceFirst()` so its equivalent to

```
Pattern inputSpace = Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.MULTILINE);  
String spaceText = "This split ";    
System.out.println(inputSpace.matcher(spaceText).replaceFirst("&amp;emsp;"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do in 2 steps:

1. indexOf(" ") will tell you where is the index
2. result = str.substring(0, index)  + str.substring(index+1, str.length())

The idea is this, you may need to adjust the index values properly according to API.

It should be faster than regexp, because there is 2x arraycopy and not need to text compile pattern matching and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Can use Apache StringUtils:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public class substituteFirstOccurrence{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String text = "Word1 Word2 Word3";

        System.out.println(StringUtils.replaceOnce(text, " ", "-"));

        // output: "Word1-Word2 Word3"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply use `yourString.replaceFirst(" ", "");` in Kotlin.